# TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate отображается только 1й уровень

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Не могу понять, где ошибка в привязке.

Делаю по примерам, однако почему-то отображается только первый элемент в дереве. Вложенные элементы не появляются

**XAML:**

```
    <TreeView x:Name="tv_nodes" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type prim:Node}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

**описание Node**

```
public class Node : IXmlSerializable
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlArray]
    public ObservableCollection<Node> Children = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
}
```

В итоге имею только первый уровень. Куда делись вложенные элементы? Что не так в привязке?

Comment: `Children` должно быть свойством, а не полем

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо, как же я так лоханулся...

Comment: Со всеми бывает :)

Comment: @tym32167 в ответ превратите комментарий, я вопрос закрою

Comment: Превратил в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Children` должно быть свойством, а не полем.